# Open a file with line numbers in more (AIX)

Tags: ksh, aix, more

How do I open a file in `more` mode with line numbers. I am using `ksh` on `AIX`

for `less` I use `-N` but for more it is not working.

`less -N filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 100% portable approach, you can use `awk`:

```
awk '{print NR,$0}' file | more
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working. How do I go to end of file in this mode.

Comment: @Aravind huh? Just like you would with any other stream opened in `more`. Hit space repeatedly. Or, just pick up the last few lines: `awk '{print NR,$0}' file | tail -n 50 | more`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nl` tool which may also be available for AIX  (e.g. part of GNU coreutils):

```
nl filename | more
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if you are familiar with `vi` you can also use that. To enable display of line numbers (in case it is not in your `~/.exrc`) simply enable it in command mode via `:set numbers` or the shorter form `:se nu`.

Comment: file size is more, i can't open in `vi` editor.